# "На завтра" и "назавтра". Особенности употребления

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов, значение-слов, слитно-раздельно

Небо начисто освободилось от облаков, обещали и **на завтра** солнечный и ясный день. А это означало, что **назавтра** я снова надолго уйду в лес.

В каких случаях стоит писать *на завтра* раздельно, а в каких -- слитно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

> Небо начисто освободилось от облаков, *обещали* и **на завтра** солнечный и
>   ясный день.

В этом предложении **на завтра** означает *обещанное* (в других контекстах: *назначенное, отложенное*) "**на завтрашний день**". Здесь это сказано в прошедшем времени (обеща*ли*), но с мысленным переносом времени повествования *в настоящее время* (в день, относительно которого определяется "**завтра**"): так можно сказать об обещаниях или планах на завтрашний день и *в настоящем или будущем времени* ("на завтра обещают хорошую погоду", "отложу на завтра"), а также в прямой речи персонажа.

> А это означало, что **назавтра** я снова надолго уйду в лес.

Здесь о *будущем действии* говорится с позиций *прошедшего времени* (нет условного переноса во времени, как в первом предложении). **Назавтра** здесь означает "**на следующий день**" (относительно времени действия глагола "означало"). Сказать так можно исключительно с позиций прошедшего времени (о предстоявшем действии), в настоящем же времени (или в прямой речи персонажа в повествовании) с тем же смыслом было бы просто "**завтра**".

Словарями *назавтра* обычно помечается как *разговорное*.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на вопрос можно найти **в толковом словаре.**

**НАЗАВТРА**, **нареч.** **Разг**. На следующий день. Н. опять было пасмурно.

**ЗАВТРА.** I. нареч. На следующий день после сегодняшнего. Приеду з. II. **неизм.; ср.** Следующий день за сегодняшним. Распорядок дня на з. Перенести на з.

**Пояснение**

1) Если речь идет о **будущем времени,** то наречия ***завтра*** и ***назавтра*** ― это синонимы и различаются только по стилю (нейтральный и разговорный):

**А это означало, что назавтра (=завтра) я снова надолго уйду в лес.**

2) Если речь идет о **прошедшем времени**, то наречие ***назавтра*** заменяет наречие ***завтра*** (это уже нейтральный стиль): Но **назавтра**  дело его окончилось плачевной развязкой. [Ф. М. Достоевский. (1846)]

3) Есть существительное ***завтра*** и его предложная форма ***на завтра.***

Небо начисто освободилось от облаков, обещая и **на завтра** (= на завтрашний день) солнечный и ясный день.

**Примеры:**

1) И это значило, что **назавтра** он должен исправить хотя бы одну двойку. [Г. А. Галахова.  (1975)]   А **назавтра** опять пошевелит ноздрями и скажет шепеляво... [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, ч. 1 (1960)]

2) **Назавтра** весь день руки её были холодны и сердце ныло. [Алексей Слаповский. Гибель гитариста (1994-1995)]

3) Бесчисленные сады Лисса благоухали цветами; дышать было свежо; а ясное небо, с высоко забравшимися в него ласточками, **обещало на завтра** такую же отраву зноя, как сегодняшний день. [А. С. Грин.  (1928)]